# How to get progress of MNIST data download?

Tags: python, pyqt5

i'm downloading the MNIST dataset and need to be able to show that in a progress bar. a) I was trying to figure out how to do that in a multithreaded fashion such that the progress bar can update at the same time as the download and b) I was wondering how to access the % downloaded because when you run the line of code

```
trainset = datasets.MNIST(root='mnistdata/', download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
```

it automatically puts the % complete in the terminal, so i assume that there is some way of getting that information.